# Meaning of "Nur so anbei."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

German climate activist Luisa Neubauer [tweets](https://twitter.com/Luisamneubauer/status/1191708722793451523):

> "Lieber @AndiScheuer, wir stehen erst seit 46 Wochen Freitags vor Ihrem Ministerium, aber falls Sie es noch nicht mitbekommen haben: Wir heißen Fridays For Future und nicht Fridays For Yesterday. Nur so anbei. Bis Freitag!"

What does "Nur so anbei." mean?

Comment: It is "freitags", not "Freitags". Nur so nebenbei.

Comment: The remaining question is, whether that's dialect or a mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Nur so anbei.

means *enclosed for no specific reason* and doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

What she wanted to say is

> Nur so nebenbei.

*Nebenbei* means *as a side note/by the way*. The *nur so* means, that *nebenbei* is to be taken ironically.

---

<sub>Nur so nebenbei: (as Matthias pointed out in a comment) it's *freitags* not *Freitags*.</sub>

Comment: I would not use "enclosed" in this translation, its meaning feels too specific in this context to me... I'd translate it with a word that's broader in meaning, e.g. "provided without specific reason".

Comment: @orithena I wouldn't use *anbei* in this context since it means *enclosed*.

Comment: According to the dictionary, it's only used in the context where you _can_ enclose something (as in a letter or package), I give you that. Removed from that context and put into the context of the question, I pick up a broader meaning from the particles alone: "bei" (somehow related to something) and "an" (near).

Comment: The distinction between "anbei" and "nebenbei" was probably taught on a friday.

Answer (score 10):

"anbei" is mostly used in letters or documents when talking about attachments:

> Anbei sende ich Ihnen die Dokumente A, B und C.
>
> Enclosed please find the documents A, B and C.

The phrase Luisa Neubauer used would probably more often put as

> Nur so nebenbei.

And, as πάντα ῥεῖ correctly explained, it means something along the line of "by the way" or "just saying".

The sentiment of the whole tweet could probably been translated as

> Dear @AndiScheuer, we've been picketing your department every Friday for only 46 weeks, but just in case you didn't notice yet: We're called "Fridays for Future", not "Fridays for Yesterday". Just sayin'. See you Friday!

"Fridays for Yesterday" is a mocking name that seems to be used by climate change sceptics in order to discredit the Fridays for Future movement.

Comment: Since "Fridays for Yesterday" has (at the moment) 7 Google Search results, which are almost all related to this tweet (including this question), I wouldn't say that it is a mocking name used by climate change denialists.

Comment: The mocking name to discredit the Fridays for Future is "Fridays for Hubraum" (Fridays for engine displacement).

Comment: @gerrit I've seen the name used to that intent, but maybe (hopefully?) it hasn't caught on so far.

Comment: @glglgl To my knowledge "Fridays for Hubraum" is an actual Facebook group whose members consider it the proponent of the opposite view to "Fridays for Future". It has been ridiculed a lot, but as far as I can tell, the people behind "Fridays for Hubraum" are serious about their cause.

Answer (score 2):

> What does "Nur so anbei." mean?

It means just the same as BTW (by the way) in English language.

The punctuation is probably a bit confusing, IMO it should be:

> > Wir heißen Fridays For Future und nicht Fridays For Yesterday **>>,<<** nur so anbei.

If a full translation helps better, it would be:

> > We're named "Fridays For Future", and not "Fridays For Yesterday" BTW.